# Text alignment of disabled JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jcombobox

I have problems with the text alignment of a disabled `JComboBox`.

In my standard use case the `ComboBox` is enabled and the text(that is longer then the component weidth) is correctly displayed from left to right:

[image]

but in some cases I have to disable the `ComboBox` which leads to this behaviour.

[image]

I have tried to set the orientation with the following lines:

```
lView.getMyComboBox().setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
```

and

```
((JLabel)lView.getMyComboBox().getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
```

but without succeed.

Could you help me find the problem?

Regards

Stefan

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something beside pure Swing ? I have tried with an example (in java 7) and it works fine.

The problem might be with your renderer.  What instance of ListCellRenderer is used by your combo ?

Mathias

Answer (score -1):

You can change the width of the JComboBox itself to fit the whole Label.